# WordPress Walker class partially working

Tags: wordpress

I am new to WordPress, not sure if I am heading in the right direction.

Essentially I have a menu being called like

```
 wp_nav_menu(array('walker' => new Nav_Header_Walker(), 'theme_location'=>'header-menu'));
```

And I am modifying the output with

```
class Nav_Header_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu{
    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $output .= '<ul class="mynav">';
    }

    function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $output .= '</ul>';
    }

    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        $output .= '<li><a href="">cat</a></li>';
    }
}
```

But it seems the only Walker functions are the ones with '_el', also I can not output any values with $item->title, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: There are other parameters for you to pass to the function such as 'container-class' or 'container'.  The parameter 'cascade' you are passing is not a valid parameter. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/

Comment: updated the post

Comment: Output the contents of the $item array so see what the properties are. I ran this against my theme and the property was $item->post_title and not 'title'

Comment: @AndrewSchultz you are correct, I should of just looked at the db naming conventions.  Go ahead and submit your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Ok great, remember, debug is your friend, always develop with it switched on :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output the contents of the $item array so see what the properties are. I ran this against my theme and the property was $item->post_title and not 'title'.  This should resolve your issue.